# Confusion regarding torque and centre of mass

Tags: rotational-dynamics

When a body slides down a rough incline plane, why does $mg \cos \theta$ and normal reaction produce no torque? And why does $mg\sin \theta$ produce torque?

Comment: Hi Raunak. We would view your question more sympathetically if you made the effort to type it properly and added a diagram to explain how quantities such as $\theta$ are defined.

Comment: i mean i think that mg passes through the centre of mass of the object and so does its components,and even the normal reaction passes through the centre. so,none of them should produce a torque right. Theta is the angle based on which the components are taken. i'm sorry that i am unable to add an image.

Comment: To specify a torque you must also specify an origin. A force may not have a torque about one origin but may have one around another. So what are you using as your origin?

Comment: I was taking the torque of the object about the centre of mass.

Answer (score 0):

None of the forces produce a torque around the center of mass. But, if the inclined plane offers some friction, then the friction definitely would produce a torque proportional to 
$mg\sin\theta$ in the other direction, assuming that $\theta$ is the angle at which the inclined plane is inclined.

Comment: Note, for clarity to the OP, that this analysis assumes the origin of coordinates is the center of mass.  But you can choose any origin you want.  With other origins, those forces *do* produce torques.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the point of rotation is where the sphere and inclined plane make contact. The vertical force that produces a torque is the weight of the sphere ($m g$). The perpendicular distance between the point of contact and the weight is $r \sin(\theta)$. The resulting torque will be $r m g \sin(\theta)$.